# SQL query that enables all entries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am developing a database and I have a table (lets say materials). I have a second table lets that I save the materials I have bought lets say purchase_elements. For example

MatID: Mat1 > quantity:3

MatID: Mat2 > quantity:4

MatID: Mat5 > quantity:2

MatID: Mat1 > quantity:5

When I want to see the material I had bought with the query

```
SELECT materials.id, 
       materials.name, 
       Sum(purchase_elements.quantity) AS QUANTITY
 FROM materials 
   INNER JOIN purchase_elements 
 ON materials.id= purchase_elements.id
 GROUP BY materials.id, 
          materials.name;
```

That shows

```
Id/name/QUANTITY
1 Mat1  8
2 Mat2  4   
5 Mat5  2
```

Is there any way the query show me not only the materials I have make purchase but all of them

```
Id/name/QUANTITY
1 Mat1  8
2 Mat2  4   
3 Mat3
4 Mat4
3 Mat5  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN, because INNER JOIN limits rows to only materials you have purchased and filters materials that are not part of the `purchase_elements` table. You will need to modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT M.id, M.name, SUM(PE.quantity) AS QUANTITY
FROM materials AS M
     LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_elements AS PE ON M.id= PE.MatID
GROUP BY M.id, M.name;
```

Comment: Where did you used the "LEFT OUTER JOIN"?

Comment: You use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` when joining two tables when you want all records in the `left-side` table to show up, whether or not the `right-side` table has associated records. So I used it when joining `materials` and `purchase_elements`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [left join](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx).

```
SELECT materials.id, 
   materials.name, 
   Sum(purchase_elements.quantity) AS QUANTITY
FROM materials 
 LEFT JOIN purchase_elements 
ON materials.id= purchase_elements.[Υλικά IID]
GROUP BY materials.id, 
      materials.name;
```